# Heroku app showing blank page. react / express/ node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, web-deployment

https://peaceful-basin-17224.herokuapp.com/

Of course, "it works on my machine".

When I look at the network, I see the assets being loaded from index.html but nothing else.
Also, for some reason the `npm run build` doesn't seem to run. I'll `heroku bash` into the app and I won't find a `/frontend/build`

I've been messing with this since last night and feel like I haven't made any progress. Any help would be appreciated!

Part of my server.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/public', 'index.html'));
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname +'frontend'));
//Serve static assests if in production 
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){ 
  //Set static folder 
  app.use(express.static('frontend/build'));
  app.get('*', (req, res)=>{ 
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'public', 'index.html'))   });
}
```

Here's my package.json:

```
 {
    "name": "backend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build"
      },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
    "@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing": "^3.0.69",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "simple-react-modal": "^0.5.1"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you install the necessary dependencies for your front end before running build?

Comment: I thought that would be taken care of by the npm install --prefix frontend in my heroku-postbuild. Would that not be the case? I don't mean that sarcastically, pretty beginner

Comment: I recently deployed an app of the same configuration, using this as launch options in my package.json `"start": "concurrently \"npm run install && npm run build\" \"npm run server\""` Where install and build both cd into my client react project.

Comment: just tried this and having the same issue, is this wrong? thanks for responding so quickly.
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "concurrently \"npm run install && npm run build\" \"npm run server\"",
  "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build"
    },

Comment: That script is pretty specific to my project, use it as a reference and build your own script. You can also read about package.json scripts [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts).

Comment: This blog helps you out to live your web app on Heroku [https://coursework.vschool.io/deploying-mern-app-to-heroku/](https://coursework.vschool.io/deploying-mern-app-to-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can delete all of this code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/public', 'index.html'));
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname +'frontend'));
//Serve static assests if in production 
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){ 
  //Set static folder 
  app.use(express.static('frontend/build'));
  app.get('*', (req, res)=>{ 
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'public', 'index.html'))   });
}
```

and put only this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './frontend/build')));
```

My react.js folder had the name "frontend" and it was at the same level with my server.js file, that's why it is one dot `./frontend/build`. And don't remove `build` name and dont change it to any other name.

And please let me know if this answer helps.